# Get routable IPV6 address from requester in OWIN when requester is on local machine

Tags: owin, ipv6

I'm working on a system with three parts that communicate over HTTP.  The parts are the Service, the ServiceRegistry, and the Client.  The Service and the ServiceRegistry are self-hosted OWIN applications.  The nature of the client doesn't matter.

In my design, the Service `POST`s to the ServiceRegistry to "register" itself.   The ServiceRegistry reads `Request.GetOwinContext().Request.RemoteIpAddress` to determine where the Service is located and `GET`s back to the Service to perform some handshaking (the port for this `GET` is supplied in the original `POST`).  Finally, the Client comes along and performs a `GET` to the ServiceRegistry asking for the location of the Service and receives back the IP address and port on which it can directly interact with the Service.

This works well when all three parts are running on different machines.

However, when the configuration is that the Service and the ServiceManager are running on MACHINE01 and the Client is running on MACHINE02 the system fails.  What appears to be happening is (when both parts are located on one machine) `RemoteIpAddress` receives a link-local version of the IPV6 address.  I strip off the Scope ID from the IPV6 address and return the address and port to the Client.  But, to the Client running on a different machine, this is an unreachable address.

Can anybody suggest how I can read the remote IP address from the OWIN request in such a way that it will be reachable from another machine on my network?

Answer (score 1):

When you are connected with any address, I don't think there is a way to get other addresses of the peer.

You could either implement and use some registry of address mappings between link locale addresses and global addresses. (Always in the hope the peer accepts requests on its global address as well.)

Or if you have access to it I'd propose to modify the requesting peer to send the request originating from its global address. This can normally achieved with source address selection. But I have no idea how you do this on the .NET platform as I am working on Unix systems.